# WPF Popup gets dislocated and unable to close

Tags: c#, wpf

Problem:

I have a popup wrapped inside a combobox the behavior works fine in all scenarios, except in one where you try to open a third party winforms window which takes abt 5 seconds to load, and during this time when you try to click on Combobox continously, the popup relocates and gets stuck at top left of the screen, and Once stuck clicking outside does not change the `IsOpen` state and remains there permanently.

On further analysis it was found that the Combobox IsDropDownOpen gets toggled from true to false state within 20ms on account of focus being captured to another control, this breaks the proper transition of popup from closed state to open state. I was able to reproduce this locally by using
`Mose.Capture(null)` inside of GripDown-IsVisibleChanged event.

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="HeaderSrc" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Segs, Mode=OneWay}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Seg, Mode=OneTime}"
    IsEnabled="{Binding IsSrcEnabled, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ComboBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Grid x:Name="GridRoot">
                <FrameworkElement x:Name="ProxyElement" attachedProperties:FrameworkElements.CellSize="{DynamicResource CellSize}" />
                <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton" Focusable="False" ClickMode="Release" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                <Popup x:Name="MyPopup" Placement="Custom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ToggleButton}" StaysOpen="True" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="True" Margin="0">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <behaviors1:PopupCallBackBehavior Alignment="Right" />
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Grid x:Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" Margin="{DynamicResource SourceSelectionDropShadowBuffer}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Grid.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect po:Freeze="True" RenderingBias="Performance" BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="0" Direction="0" Color="Black" Opacity="0.75" />
                        </Grid.Effect>
                        <ScrollViewer PanningMode="Both" CanContentScroll="True" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Style="{StaticResource SourceSelectionPopupScrollViewerStyle}" >
                            <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" Margin="0" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Template>
</ComboBox>
```

PopupCallBackBehavior.cs:

```
protected override void OnAttached()
{
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.CustomPopupPlacementCallback = this.HandlePopupPlacement;
        this.AssociatedObject.Closed += OnAssociatedObjectOnClosed;
}

private CustomPopupPlacement[] HandlePopupPlacement(Size thePopupSize, Size theTargetSize, Point theOffset)
{
 var aAnchorPoint = (this.Alignment == PopupAlignmentType.Left)
                ? new Point(-thePopupSize.Width + theTargetSize.Width, theTargetSize.Height)
                : new Point(0, theTargetSize.Height);
        var aHorizontalPlacement = new CustomPopupPlacement(aAnchorPoint, PopupPrimaryAxis.None);
           return new[] { aHorizontalPlacement, aHorizontalPlacement };
}
```

Debug Traces:
I tried to add few logs by subscribing to combobox, togglebutton and popups eventhandler to see the flow of sequence.

Sequence of events when issue is seen:

```
Combobox_DropDownOpened IsDropDownOpen = True 
Combobox_DropDownClosed IsDropDownOpen = False 
GridDropDownIsVisibileChanged IsVisible=True and Visibility.Visible 
Popup_Opened IsOpen=False
```

Sequence of events in working scenario:

```
Combobox_DropDownOpened, IsDropDownOpen = True 
GridDropdown_IsVisibleChanged True and Visible 
HandlePopupPlacement Method 
Popup_Opened IsOpen=True 
Toggle Checked, IsChecked =  True
Combobox_DropDownClosed, IsDropDownOpen = False 
Toggle Uncheched, IsChecked = False 
GridDropdown_IsVisibleChanged False and Visible
Popup_Closed, IsOpen = False
```

Let me know if more information is required, thanks

Comment: What is PopupAlignmentType?

Comment: @emoacht = Its an enum with "Left" and "Right" as values

Comment: I see. I guess the calculation inside internal [UpdatePosition](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/Popup.cs,2005) method won't work well with `CustomPopupPlacement` provided by your custom method at the particular case but have no idea what exactly happens.